# Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline No package found error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline:

```
trigger:
- master
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: 'Build'
    steps:
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        inputs:
          command: 'build'
          configuration: 'Release'
          projects: |
            $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/*.csproj
          arguments: --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
      - task: ArchiveFiles@2
        displayName: 'Archive files'
        inputs:
          rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output'
          includeRootFolder: false
          archiveType: zip
          archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
          replaceExistingArchive: true
      - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        artifact: drop
- stage: Test
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
    - job: Deploy
      displayName: 'Deploy to Test'
      steps:
      - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
        inputs:
          ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
          azureSubscription: 'xxx'
          appType: 'webApp'
          WebAppName: 'xxx'
          package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

When I run it I get

```
Error: No package found with specified pattern: /home/vsts/work/1/drop/13325.zip<br/>Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.
```

The build stage produces an artifact, and it is in the 'drop' directory, so I can not wrap my mind around  it why publish task can not find it?

Comment: Could you try instead of `package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'`  `'$(Build.StagingDirectory)/**/*.zip'` . As you defined your pipeline the artifact should be located on a path like `home/vsts/work/1/a/..`

Comment: @GeralexGR I tried it, but it didn't work, got slightly different error message: Error: No package found with specified pattern: /home/vsts/work/1/a/**/*.zip

Comment: Please start by looking at the Azure Pipelines documentation. The problem here is that you aren't using a `deployment` job (or explicitly downloading artifacts from the `Build` stage) in your `Test` stage. The documentation is extensive and includes numerous examples of how to accomplish this.

Comment: @DanielMann I'm not sure explicitly downloading will help, I have tried the same pipeline with explicit downloading before deployment, it didn't work.

Comment: @anystacy The pipeline you posted is **not downloading the artifact**. There is no conceivable way it would work. You have to either explicitly `- download` it, or use a `deployment` job. If you're still receiving an error once it's downloading the artifact, you have a *separate* issue, which is that you're not providing the correct path. You can look at the `- download` step to confirm the location and make the appropriate updates.

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniel indicated you will also need a download artifacts task inside your `Test` stage as the different stages keep separate working directories.

```
- stage: Test
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
    - job: Deploy
      displayName: 'Deploy to Test'
      steps:
      - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
        inputs:
          buildType: 'current'
          downloadType: 'single'
          artifactName: 'drop'
          downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'      
      - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
        inputs:
          ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
          azureSubscription: 'xxx'
          appType: 'webApp'
          WebAppName: 'xxx'
          package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```